# Is there a way to suppress all LuaTeX output except errors?

Tags: luatex, terminal-output

Basically, TeX has a lot to say, and I'm not really interested in most of it. If I were, I'd read the log. The silence package suppresses output, but it suppresses output to the log as well, and further, it only suppresses some of the output, not nearly enough. I don't want hundreds of lines of output to appear every time I run the command, but I still want to be told about errors and be given a prompt.

I know that I can run something like

```
lualatex myfile.tex 1>/dev/null
```

or batch-mode to simply suppress all output. But it's useful when LuaTeX tells me about a compiling error, and I would like to keep that while getting rid of everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reporting callbacks to turn off most messages, for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\zzz

\end{document}
```

produces terminal output of

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./pp009.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(usi
ng read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /home/dav
idc/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.652 seconds
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo(load luc: /usr/local/texlive/2017
/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc)))
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (./pp009.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \zzz

? 
(./pp009.aux))
 365 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 4 attribute, 46 glue_spec, 4 attribute_lis
t, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:7,3:1,4:1,5:4,7:1,8:1,9:1

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on pp009.log.
```

but

```
\directlua{
function be_quiet ()
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('start_run', be_quiet, 'stop start run')
luatexbase.add_to_callback('stop_run', be_quiet, 'stop stop run')
luatexbase.add_to_callback('start_page_number', be_quiet, 'stop start page')
luatexbase.add_to_callback('stop_page_number', be_quiet, 'stop stop page')
luatexbase.add_to_callback('start_file', be_quiet, 'stop start file')
luatexbase.add_to_callback('stop_file', be_quiet, 'stop stop file')
luatexbase.add_to_callback('show_warning_message', be_quiet, 'stop show warning message')
}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\zzz

\end{document}
```

Produces terminal output of

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./pp009.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(usi
ng read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /home/dav
idc/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.664 seconds
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.

Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(load luc: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmr
oman10-regular.luc)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.18 \zzz

?
```

Comment: actually as written it suppresses the log as well but instead of doin nothing the supplied functions could write to the log but not the terminal.

Comment: Could this code also suppress warnings messages such as `Overfull \hbox (128.32224pt too wide) in paragraph at lines...` and `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines...` ? Basically any warning and informational messages except for errors? I tried it, but still see all these messages on screen. There are so many of them. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser they are standard tex messages: set `\hfuzz=\maxdimen`  and `\hbadness=10000` although it would be better to fix the document rather than hide the messages if you expect anyone to read the document

Comment: I did that. But I still see them   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW3Vr.png)  I added `\hfuzz=\maxdimen` and `\hbadness=10000` in the preamble: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuk9f.png) may be I need to use different values for these?

Comment: don't ask questions as comments on unrelated answers: make a new question with a real example. @Nasser

Comment: I was going to ask the same exact question posted here. Which is how to only show error messages and nothing else. I googled and found this question. If I have posted same question, it would be closed as duplicate. Now you are saying I should make new question?  it is really  hard to know what the rules are in this forum.